# react-native install error using the command in Cmd

Tags: react-native, npm

I encountered an error:

> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I am trying to install React native using the script:

> "npm install -g react-native-cli"

but it is not working,
I used the node.exe file from: "https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/" with a 64-bit Windows Binary (.zip) version, getting the message: "npm should be run outside của thay đổi node, trong bạn thiết bị thường.
(Press Control-D to exit.) "
I have read some similar questions, but I have not found my answer yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

That's because either there's some issue with your node installation or the path is not added. Firstly check if the path is added or not(Please follow the [Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/npm-is-not-recognized-from-visual-studio) it might come in handy for you). If they are alright and you are still facing the issue let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder.
I think I downloaded it.
I think there is a difference between the two versions of nodejs 10.16.0 LTS and the current 12.6.0.
I have used the previous version 12.6.0 but it did not work as expected. Sorry for not looking carefully, I asked @@